# How to display results returned by DataTable?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, data-binding

I have the following code in my DataAccess class:

```
    public IEnumerable<Object> getAllPersons()
    {
        string CommandText = "Select * from Person";
        SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand(CommandText, oConnection);
        oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        // Create a datatable and SqlDataAdapter
        SqlDataAdapter oAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        oAdapter.SelectCommand = oCommand;
        DataTable oDataTable = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            // Open Connection and fill the datatable using the SqlDataAdapter
            oConnection.Open();
            oAdapter.Fill(oDataTable);
            return oDataTable.AsEnumerable();
        }
        catch (Exception oException)
        {
            throw oException;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close the SqlConnection
            oConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

In my presentation layer i need to bind this returned DataTable to my grid, here's my code:

```
       DataAccess mydataaccess = new DataAccess();
        IEnumerable<object> personList=mydataaccess .getAllPersons();

        GridView1.DataSource = personList;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

This results in the following:

[image]

How can I display the actual columns and data resulted from the DataTable ?

Comment: How did you manage to compile this code?

Comment: @Steve, I guess i understood what you mean, there is a missing section in my code, please check the edited code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding of the `IEnumerable<object>` to the DataSource of your grid fails.
You need to convert back your sequence of DataRow to an object that could be assigned to the DataSource property.

You could change your GetPerson method to return an `IEnumerble<DataRow>` instead of a generic object

```
public IEnumerable<DataRow> getAllPersons()
```

and in the binding call

```
DataAccess mydataaccess = new DataAccess();
IEnumerable<DataRow> personList=mydataaccess .getAllPersons();

GridView1.DataSource = personList.CopyToDataTable();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

But at this point I am wondering why you don't return directly a DataTable from your `getAllPersons` method

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follow. You can more easily bind to DataTable instead of IEnumerable.

```
public DataTable getAllPersons()
{
    string CommandText = "Select * from Person";
    SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand(CommandText, oConnection);
    oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    // Create a datatable and SqlDataAdapter
    SqlDataAdapter oAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    oAdapter.SelectCommand = oCommand;
    DataTable oDataTable = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        // Open Connection and fill the datatable using the SqlDataAdapter
        oConnection.Open();
        oAdapter.Fill(oDataTable);
    }
    catch (Exception oException)
    {
        throw oException;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close the SqlConnection
        oConnection.Close();
    }
   return oDataTable;
}
```

In your aspx file add following property.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" />
```

This will show every column in your object, therefore you will most probably want something like following.

```
<asp:GridView ID="productGridView" Runat="server" 
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Colum Name A"  DataField="ColumNameA">
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Colum Name B"  DataField="ColumNameB">
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I got that in my aspx but it doesn't help